# swift struct as function parameter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, struct, parameters

I have a struct/model that I store some JSON data to fill my tableview:

```
import SwiftyJSON

struct MyData {

    let valOne: Int
    let valTwo: String
    let valThree: Int

    init(json: JSON) {
        valOne = json["some_data"].intValue
        valTwo = json["auc_data"].stringValue
        valThree = json["auc_data"].intValue
    }
}
```

Then in my tableview I have a custom cell class that I use when I write out my data:

```
let data = MyData[indexPath.row]

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell") as! CustomTableViewCell

cell.configureCellWithData(data)
```

What I want to do is to pass the struct as a parameter to the **configureCellWithData()** but I am not sure how to declare it.

Instead of doing something like:

```
func configureCellWithData(dataOne: Int, dataTwo: String, dataThree: Int) {

}
```

then

```
configureCellWithData(data.valOne,data.valTwo,data.valThree)
```

I dont want to have many parameters instead I want to send the struct right away

Comment: Have you tried this way ?  func configureCellWithData(data: MyData) { }

Comment: The `let data = MyData[indexPath.row]` line doesn't make sense. I assume you have some property defined like `var dataObjects = [MyData]()` or something like that, and you'd then do `let data = dataObjects[indexPath.row]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
func configureCellWith(data: MyData) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Yep, or if Swift 3, perhaps `func configureCell(with data: MyData) { ... }`.